# Logic to check all values of a calculation to be NaN in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have problem with logic function inside object

I'm getting info from html page, there is usually about 50 objects to check:

```
for (var numbers in table) {
    let alfa = table[numbers].nl + table[numbers].n2;

    if (alfa < 201) {
        console.log(`found it in: ${numbers}`);
    }
}
```

sometimes variable 'alfa' is NaN (what is not problem) but how can I check case when every item (variable: alfa) in loop is NaN?

I need handle function only when every item in loop is NaN, I don't want to do anything with code if a few items are NaN and rest are numbers

Thank you guys for solution

Answer (score 1):

If you get `NaN` as a result of addition, then either `table[numbers].nl` or `table[numbers].n2` must be `NaN`.

You can check whether all of these values are `NaN` by using [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and `Number.isNaN`:

```
if (Object.values(table).every(v => Number.isNaN(v.nl) || Number.isNaN(v.n2))) {
    console.log("All are NaN")
} else {
    // do the normal thing
}
```

Of course you could also just do the addition and check the  result:

```
if (Object.values(table).every(v => Number.isNaN(v.nl + v.n2))) {
    console.log("All are NaN")
}
```

Comment: `all` i suppose it's typo, you meant `every` right ?

Comment: Whoops, yeah! Different languages call these differently :-/

Comment: I changed .all to. every in nodejs script, and it works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just check for conditions as follows:

```
for (var numbers in table) {
    let alfa = table[numbers].nl + table[numbers].n2;

    if (Number.isNaN(alfa) && alfa < 201) {
        console.log(`found it in: ${numbers}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: `alfa !== NaN` will always be true. You have to use `Number.isNaN`

Comment: well, I need to re-log account when every variable called 'alfa' is NaN, but if a few items are NaN its totally fine

Comment: @Felix Kling Thanks for correcting I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JS function     includes() to check if an array contains the item  you are looking for. Returns true or false.

```
if (arr.includes(!NaN)){
    console.log("Doesnt includes Nan");
}else{
    console.log("includes Nan")
}
```

Applied to your code it would be:

```
if(table.includes(!NaN){ 
// Handle this case
}else{
for (var numbers in table) {
        let alfa = table[numbers].nl + table[numbers].n2;

        if (alfa < 201) {
            console.log(`found it in: ${numbers}`);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First simply [**`Array.map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) all values calculated and then use [**`Array.find()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to check if even one of them is not `NaN` and return immediately.

```
const alfaValues = table.map(t => t.n1 + t.n2);
const foundNotNaN = alfaValues.find(o => !isNaN(o));

//if there is a value in foundNotNaN then all values are not NaN
if(foundNotNaN){

}else{
    //all values are NaN
}
```

**Examples:**
*How can I check case when every item (variable: alfa) in loop is NaN?*

**Case 1:** Where every alfa (obj.n1 + obj.n2) is not NaN

```
const x = [{n1: NaN, n2: 3}, {n1: 5, n2: 7}];
const alfaValuesX = x.map(t => t.n1 + t.n2);
//results in [NaN, 12]
const foundNotNaNX = alfaValuesX.find(o => !isNaN(o));
//results in 12
//conclusion: every calculation of alfa (obj.n1 + obj.n2) is not NaN atleast one is found
```

**Case 2:** Where every alfa (obj.n1 + obj.n2) would result in NaN

```
const y = [{n1: NaN, n2: 3}, {n1: 5, n2: NaN}, {n1:NaN, n2:NaN}];
const alfaValuesY = y.map(t => t.n1 + t.n2);
//results in [NaN, NaN, NaN]
const foundNotNaNY = alfaValuesY.find(o => !isNaN(o));
//results in undefined
//conclusion: every calculation of alfa (obj.n1 + obj.n2) is NaN
```

Comment: *"if there is a value in foundNotNaN then all values are not NaN"* OP said that that's not the case. Some might be NaN others may not.

Comment: What did I miss. After `.map` if any of the values found that is not `NaN` that means every caculated sum ( `alfa` example) is not going to be `NaN` else vice-versa. Which is what the OP wants ..to check when all values would `NaN` isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's what the OP wants, but I mean that  *one* value not being NaN doesn't imply that *all* are. From the post: *"I need handle function only when every item in loop is NaN, I don't want to do anything with code if a few items are NaN and rest are numbers"*

Comment: @FelixKling Not sure if I am not able to understand something silly. Bear with me pls.. But with this **`alfaValues.find(o => !isNaN(o));`** would return **`undefined`** **when it reached till the end and none of them were** *isNaN() as falsy*. If any of them weren't it would return with a value that mean at least one of them was not `NaN` rest *could be/could not be* and that's a confirmation that all values are not `NaN`.

Comment: OK, lets take this example: `[{n1: NaN, n2: 3}, {n1: 5, n2: 7}]`. The sum of *one* of them is not `NaN`, but not *all* of them are not `NaN`. That's all I'm pointing out. I don't understand how you get from *"rest could be/could not be"* to *"that's a confirmation that all values are not NaN"*.

Comment: @FelixKling Updated the answer with the example u mentioned and another one to test this out. And it does give what is intended.

Comment: I am not debating that it works as intended. I know it works. I'm just pointing out your choice of words. Same in the eexample: *"every calculation of alfa (obj.n1 + obj.n2) is not NaN"* No it's not. The first one is NaN. *Some* `alfa` values are NaN and some are not. Am I not expressing myself clearly?

Comment: @FelixKling Oh! I get it ..might seem to a read like *every calculation of alfa (obj.n1 + obj.n2) is !NaN* but that is not what I meant and which is suppose to imply that it is a case **where not all evalulations would be NaN** and that's what the best I could come up with english. If I have understood your point correctly, might be the case.